# How to extract brush names from ABR format

Tags: adobe-photoshop, brush, file-format, corel-painter

I recently received [a set of ABR brushes](https://www.dropbox.com/s/g3zcdjumnusuni1/Evenant-Concept-Art-Brush-Pack.abr?dl=0) (link may not work for everyone) that I would like to use in *Corel Painter 2019*. The *Corel Painter* import works insofar as that the brushes show up, but no names do (and on the site I got the brushes from, they say that the brushes do have names). I've found references to [AbrMate](https://web.archive.org/web/20181211162231/http://www.texturemate.com/abrMate) and [AbrViewer](https://sourceforge.net/projects/abrviewer/), but neither import this format. Once I upgraded Gimp 2.10.18 (2.10.8 didn't recognize the file format, claiming it was "File format 10", it imports the brushes, but again without names. Having a brush named "Evanart-concept-art-57" doesn't help me much.

There was a time when these file formats could be looked up on the internet, but I'm failing to find any documentation of this one. Does anyone know of a tool, or a source for the current file format?

Comment: If you want to read the .abr file for that, here's the format description (on page 50): http://oldschoolprg.x10.mx/downloads/ps6ffspecsv2.pdf

Comment: Interesting. If I'm reading this right, brush names are not stored, which gives me my answer, other than that apparently they do show up when loaded in Photoshop.

Answer (score 1):

ABR brushes are a Photoshop brush format, and really only work properly in Photoshop. GIMP has its own brush formats such as GBR and GIH, although it can import ABR brushes, that doesn't mean they will work properly.  I don't know much about CorelPainter unfortunately, but I suspect it will be similar.  Perhaps it would be better to look for native brush formats for the application you are using.

Comment: And I do have a lot of brushes already. However, there are a lot of Photoshop brushes out there, most of them free, and this feels like it's a technical issue that should be easy enough to fix with the right tool.